# Opening .tif and .tfw in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I am in the process of switching from MapInfo to QGIS.

I have a stack of historic map tiles in .tif with accompanying .tfw files. These help place the tif into it’s true spatial location. For each tif and tfw I also have a separate tab file that brings the tiff and tfw together. On top of that I have a seamless tab files that opens all the tab files together in one (so that users do not need to open each tab file separately).

I need to replicate all this in QGIS. How do bring in the tif into QGIS and associate it it to it corresponding tfw? (I know how to bring a tif in, but not how to link it to the tfw). In addition does QGIS have the equivalent of a MapInfo seamless tab file to open all the files together in one transaction?

Comment: Gdalbuildvrt builds a GDAL VRT file that does the same thing as seamless tab.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#gdalbuildvirtualraster

Answer (score 4):

Normally, QGIS will automatically find .tfw and draw the raster on its correct coordinates. If not, you need to search for the tool `assign projection`. Then set the raster to your desired coordinate system. good luck.